# Hash map get method

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Please explain output of below code. I guessed it null , because command line arguments are different than its key. But it is not correct explanation. It is null because friends class doesnot override equals and hashcode() methods.

But why?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Birthdays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Friends, String> hm = new HashMap<Friends, String>();
        hm.put(new Friends("Charis"), "Summer 2009");
        hm.put(new Friends("Draumur"), "Spring 2002");
        Friends f = new Friends(args[0]);
        System.out.println(hm.get(f));
    }
}

class Friends {
    String name;
    Friends(String n) { name = n; }
}
```

And the command line invocation:
java Birthdays Draumur

Answer (score 1):

`args[0]` will contain the string `"Draumur"`, so that is not the reason for the program printing `null`.

A `HashMap` is a hash table, and it finds elements in it based on the hash value of the key. If you don't override the hash method, Java will calculate the hash value based on the object identity, so two different `Friends` objects, even with the same `name` inside, will not be guaranteed to hash to the same value.

You would also need to write an `equals` method, since if you don't override it, Java will also consider two different `Friends` objects not to be equal, even with the same `name` inside.

In summary, you need to override the `hashCode` method so the `HashMap` can find the `Friends` object, and you need to override the `equals` method so the `HashMap`, when it has found it, can see that it is the object it is searching for.

Here is a possible new version of the `Friends` class (and I would also suggest you call it `Friend`, since one such object represents one single friend):

```
class Friends {
    String name;
    Friends(String n) { name = n; }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Friends))
            return false;
        Friends rhs = (Friends)o;
        return (name.equals(rhs.name));
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get` method of a map return the value of the `key` where map key ".equals" to researched key

Your Friends key do not implements `equals`, so the default one from `Object` is used, which is a "==" compare (true only if it is the same object).

`Get` will only give you something if you use the exact same object you `put` as key.

Answer (score 0):

> command line arguments are different than its key

Not sure I understand that logic...
`args = {"Draumur"}`
`new Friends(args[0]) = new Friends("Dramur")`

A key like that was placed in the map already, but a Friend is not comparable to other Friend objects via a hashcode or equality otherwise.

If you had a HashMap of String to String, then `get("Dramur")` would not be null.

Comment: args[0] = "Dramur" or args[0] = "java"?

Comment: `java` is the executable. `Birthdays` is the main class. Everything else is `args`